# How to create temporary pages in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, temporary-files

We are in a wordpress page.
This page is full of links.
Thoses links direct to non-wordpress pages.

How to:
Keep the links in memory.
On click on a link -> Create a temporary wordpress page -> go to the new wordpress page.
In this new temporary wp page, show the url adress.

Is it possible?

Comment: If you don't like someone's answer, you can leave a comment *politely* explaining that it doesn't work for you. [Suggesting an edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2309551) that defaces their answer with overt rudeness is not likely to get you far here. Also, if you find that people are not understanding your question, you should strongly consider [edit]ing to make it more clear what you're looking for.

Comment: I just typed something when i thought i could change your answer, i found it funny. But in facts it was not possible. I meant no harm. Its no big deal if you have not understood my question. Sorry.

Comment: It was not my answer. And it wasn't funny. How would you like it if I did that to your question? Changed it to: "This is a stupid question. I cannot understand English. Blah blah blah" You'd be pretty upset, I imagine.

Comment: well i just discover "takeover" question function, i didn't thought it would work. Don't get upset with that little..

Answer (score -1):

YOu can use this plugin to do so
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-exit-box-lite/

Comment: This plugin is used to make an ad when people leave the website. What i want is to create temporary files that would host the content of the external link, and then call it with a curl string.

Comment: well i didn't, but i guess its because this is not about making a temporary page but about making a popup when people leave a website.